# Bluetooth headset - how to increase volume?

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

My taotronics bluetooth (in-ear) headset is connected as a A2DP-device to my laptop.

When I set their volume to their maximum value, it still is considerably quieter than in a similar situation, e.g. when they are connected to my phone. (I actually haven't had them on maximum volume when connected to my phone. That certainly would hurt my ears.)

A click on "info" in the headset's context menu in Blueman shows this info:

```
Address ---- [EDITED]
AddressType public
Name TAOTRONICS SoundLiberty 92
Alias TAOTRONICS SoundLiberty 92
Class 0x240404
Appearance 0x0000
Icon audio-card
Paired ja
Trusted nein
Blocked nein
LegacyPairing nein
Connected ja
UUIDs 00000000-0000-0000-0099-aabbccddeeff Proprietär
      0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Audio-Ausgabe
      0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Fernsteuerungsziel
      0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Verbessertes Audio-Profil (A2DP)
      0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Fernsteuerung
      0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Handsfree
Adapter /org/bluez/hci0
```

=> How do I get to increase their volume although pulseaudio's setting for the headset is already at 100%?

Answer (score 0):

PulseAudio devices can go above 100%.

On my i3 desktop, I map my volume keys with:

```
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo -5%
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo +4%
```

This means it will continue to get louder as long as I keep pushing `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` without limit.

Comment: I think I am able to mimic your commands by changing the slider. While that is a working solution strictly on the technical level, the output then is over-controlled (usually known as "distorted").